# What type of tree traversal does the ast module use?

Tags: python, stack, abstract-syntax-tree, tree-traversal

What type of tree traversal does `ast` use (specifically `ast.NodeVisitor()`)? When I created a stack and pushed each node that was traversed into the stack the results seemed to be a 'breadth first' tree traversal. Meaning that the order was dependent on the level in the tree.

Ex. Tree looks like

```
Module
  Assign
    Name
      Store
    Call
      Attribute
        Str
        Load
```

and the stack looks like

```
[Module,Assign,Name,Call,Store,Attribute,Str,Load]
```

Ex. Code

```
stack = []
class a(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Num(self,node):
        stack.append(node)
        ...
        return node

    ...                      #this is all the other visit_*() functions

    def visit_Str(self,node):
        stack.append(node)
        ...
        return node

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with open('some_file.py','r') as pt:
        tree = ast.parse(pt)
    new_tree = a()
    new_tree_edit = ast.fix_missing_locations(new_tree.visit(tree)) # I have tried with and without calling fix_missing_locations and got the same results.
    print stack
```

Comment: You mean the `ast.walk()` function, or the `ast.NodeVisitor()`?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters - I meant ast.NodeVisitor(), but do you know if the ast.walk() method use a different traversal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `ast.walk()` function walks the tree breath-first; see the [`ast.py` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/ast.py#l203):

```
def walk(node):
    """
    Recursively yield all descendant nodes in the tree starting at *node*
    (including *node* itself), in no specified order.  This is useful if you
    only want to modify nodes in place and don't care about the context.
    """
    from collections import deque
    todo = deque([node])
    while todo:
        node = todo.popleft()
        todo.extend(iter_child_nodes(node))
        yield node
```

New nodes are pushed into a queue, the next node being traversed is the front of the queue.

If you wanted a depth-first traversal, use a subclass of [`ast.NodeVisitor()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) instead; it will walk the tree using recursion; `NodeVisitor.visit()` calls `NodeVisitor.generic_visit()` unless a more node-specific visitor method is defined, and `NodeVisitor.generic_visit()` calls `NodeVisitor.visit()` again for child nodes:

```
class NodeVisitor(object):
    """
    A node visitor base class that walks the abstract syntax tree and calls a
    visitor function for every node found.  This function may return a value
    which is forwarded by the `visit` method.

    This class is meant to be subclassed, with the subclass adding visitor
    methods.

    Per default the visitor functions for the nodes are ``'visit_'`` +
    class name of the node.  So a `TryFinally` node visit function would
    be `visit_TryFinally`.  This behavior can be changed by overriding
    the `visit` method.  If no visitor function exists for a node
    (return value `None`) the `generic_visit` visitor is used instead.

    Don't use the `NodeVisitor` if you want to apply changes to nodes during
    traversing.  For this a special visitor exists (`NodeTransformer`) that
    allows modifications.
    """

    def visit(self, node):
        """Visit a node."""
        method = 'visit_' + node.__class__.__name__
        visitor = getattr(self, method, self.generic_visit)
        return visitor(node)

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        """Called if no explicit visitor function exists for a node."""
        for field, value in iter_fields(node):
            if isinstance(value, list):
                for item in value:
                    if isinstance(item, AST):
                        self.visit(item)
            elif isinstance(value, AST):
                self.visit(value)
```

If you do subclass `NodeVisitor` (or it's derived version, `NodeTransformer`), do remember to also call `super(YourClass, self).generic_visit(node)` in your specific `visit_*` methods to continue to traverse the tree.

Comment: The results that I got above was from using a class that extended ast.NodeTransformer. And then pushing each new node into the stack within the visit_*() methods. So this makes me think that ast.NodeVisitor uses breadth first search. Sorry for being so vague, but am I missing something? I will post some example code.

Comment: @baallezx: your `NodeTransformer` subclass doesn't appear to visit child nodes *at all*; each of the `visit_*` methods must call `super(a, self).generic_visit(node)` for childnodes to be visited.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how could you traverse an AST and get all the paths (from root to its terminal nodes)? Is that possible with generic vist?

Comment: @tumbleweed: not sure why you'd want to do that? `NodeVisitor` doesn't visit paths, it visits nodes depth-first. You could keep a stack as an instance attribute, add `item` to the top of the stack just before you call `self.visit(item)` and pop it from the stack again when `self.visit(item)` returns, and then that stack is the full 'path' from root to currently visited node.